# How to break life cycle of Service Worker when caching the whole page?

Tags: angular, service-worker

I am having trouble with a service worker on a javascript page.

I installed it and unfortunately he created a cache of the whole page, so also from the sw.js, main.js, index.html.

I changed the page and fixed the "whole caching"-feature but a lot of visitors have still the old page, the old worker and therefore are never able to get the new page. The service workers of them still fetch cached index.html and it also seem not to update itself because he fetches the sw.js (service worker's javascript file) also from local cache.

It works, when I hard reload the page, but I do not think that any significant amount users do such a thing.

How can I break the lifecycle of a service worker? Is there any known workaround or have I just locked out the users with the old workers?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change some of the lines in your service worker file. Browser will consider it as an new service worker file and try to install the updated one. In this way you can restart the lifecycle of the serive worker.

During Activation event, delete all the caches.

```
function activateSW() {
  return caches.keys().then(cacheKeys => {
      cacheKeys.forEach(cacheKey => {
        caches.delete(cacheKey);
      });
    });
  }
}

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  event.waitUntil(activateSW());
  event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});
```

Comment: I already changed my SW-File. But the browsers do not update it. It seems like the browser also checks only the cached SW file on local, but this does not make sense I think :D

Comment: Your code works :) i added it on the end of my service worker. Now users have to visit my page two another times and get the updated page. Thanks a lot.